# How can I find gameobject with tag that are childs of a specific parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void UpdateOrAddShaderPrefabToDoors()
    {
        GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft);
        GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorRight);

        List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();

        HashSet<GameObject> prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove = new HashSet<GameObject>();
        allDoors.ForEach(doorGameObject =>
        {
            List<GameObject> shadersChildren = new List<GameObject>();
            for (int i=0; i<doorGameObject.transform.childCount ;i++)
            {
                if (doorGameObject.transform.GetChild(i).name.StartsWith(c_doorShieldFxLocked))
                {
                    shadersChildren.Add(doorGameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
                }
            }
            foreach (GameObject shader in shadersChildren)
            {
                GameObject outermostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(shader);
                prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove.Add(outermostPrefabInstanceRoot);
            }
        });

        foreach (GameObject parent in prefabParentsOfDoorsNeedRemove)
        {
            Modify(parent, RemoveFunc);
        }

        HashSet<GameObject> prefabParentsOfDoors = new HashSet<GameObject>();
        allDoors.ForEach(doorGameObject =>
        {
            GameObject outermostPrefabInstanceRoot = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(doorGameObject);
            prefabParentsOfDoors.Add(outermostPrefabInstanceRoot);
        });

        foreach (GameObject parent in prefabParentsOfDoors)
        {
            AddShaderToPrefab(parent);
        }
    }
```

When doing :

```
GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft);
GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorRight);
```

It will find all "Door_Left" and "Door_Right" but some of them are childs of other gameobjects and I want to find the door left and door right only that are childs of : Wall_Door_Long_01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

`GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft).Where(o => o.transform.parent.name == "Wall_Door_Long_01");`

You might want to use string compare rather than == but, as an example.

Comment: @OP: I would rather provide the given parent `Transform` reference and do `o => o.transform.parent == parent`. Doing stuff by `string` is always a bit dirty

Comment: string of course is dirty but I was under the impression all doors needed to be found, therefore going by one transform wouldnt work, it would need to be an array and therefore in a way if you knew all the parents you'd probably be better off checking if they had doors

Comment: I just saw now in my case that there are two possible parents for the left and right doors. Wall_Door_Long_01 and/or Wall_Door_Long_02 I wonder if you can make it multiple parents using Where ?

Comment: Of course you an, you an so where( o => o.transform.parent.name == "this" || o.transform.parent.name == "that")

Answer (score 0):

You could check all child of that object.

```
List<GameObject> doorsLeft = new List<GameObject>();
foreach (Transform child in transform){
    if (child.tag == tag){
        doorsLeft.add(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't find nested children though ... Also rather use `child.CompareTag()` which is more secure against typos etc. since it throws an exception while `==` fails silently -> really hard to debug!