# How can I extend the FindObjectsByTag to filter multiple parents of the found objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private List<GameObject> FindDoors(string[] parents)
    {
        GameObject[] doorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorLeft);
        GameObject[] doorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(c_doorRight);

        List<GameObject> allDoors = doorsLeft.Union(doorsRight).ToList();

        List<GameObject> toRemove = new List<GameObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < allDoors.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < parents.Length; x++)
            {
                if (allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != parents[x])
                {
                    toRemove.Add(allDoors[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var it in toRemove)
        {
            allDoors.Remove(it);
        }

        foreach (GameObject door in allDoors)
        {
            Debug.Log("Door Parent : " + door.transform.parent);
        }

        return allDoors;
    }
```

Usage :

```
var allDoors = FindDoors(new string[]{ "Wall_Door_Long_01", "Wall_Door_Long_02" });
```

But in the function FindDoors the return allDoors is empty. I think the problem is at this IF :

```
if (allDoors[i].transform.parent.name != parents[x])
```

Once it's Wall_Door_Long_01 so if it's Wall_Door_Long_01 it will not remove the item but next it's Wall_Door_Long_02 so now the it's true and will remove the even if the parent name is Wall_Door_Long_01 and same if it's Wall_Door_Long_02

And then in the end it will remove all the items. But I want it to remove only doors that the parents of them is not Wall_Door_Long_01 and not Wall_Door_Long_02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your way didnt work: The way you did it, you looped through all the doors possible parents and said if you arent it remove, well, it could be say A or B, if it was B it would have been removed because it wasnt A.

Along the lines of previously [From your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282276/how-can-i-find-gameobject-with-tag-that-are-childs-of-a-specific-parent): Just like before you can do `.Where(o => parents.Contains(o.transform.parent.name));` if parents is a list, itss late and its been a hard day I dont remember if linq lets you do the same with arrays (sorry, but its a small thing)